# Webform remote post, configure fields

Tags: webforms, 10

We have a webform and we need to send data to a multiple endpoints using remote post options.
Drupal10 does not allow (?) to change field names when we send them to 3-th party systems and since we have 2+ endpoints we send data to - we can't just rename them on webform.

We are looking for a possibility to do something like this:

webform.Location should be sent as City to remote post #1
webform.Location should be sent as Address to remote post #2

As of now I don't see how to solve that with webform module.

[image]

Comment: Did writing a custom handler emerge as one of your options?

Comment: Webform doesn't support those requirements so yeah, a custom handler is the way to go